# put imageview over the webview in android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have a one problem raised when i developing.

MY XML file data:
      I have using the one webview in fill_parent in xml file,and over i have using the image view,bottom layout i have using the button that is next and previous buttons.

My problems is i wont touch the webview content, want touch only the image view content,but when i touch the image view content ,webview content scrolled ,i don't know why?could you anyone differentiate this view?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>



<android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:scrollbars="none">
</android.webkit.WebView>

</RelativeLayout>`
```

advance thanks for your suggestions....

Comment: Show your image snapshot exactly how do you want it?

Comment: Alter the position of Webview and Imageview i.e. In your layout first add Webview then Imageview

Comment: i don't want to touch the webview content.i want only touch the imageview content.what can i do for that?

Answer (score 0):

Change layout like this or use `Framelayout` instead add `Imageview`on top of `webview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <android.webkit.WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
    android:scrollbars="none">
 <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</android.webkit.WebView>
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reverse the order of views. i.e. ImageView after Webview

Comment: This is not your answer. This must be comment!! So please familiar with this one..

Comment: i  did what your told,but i didn't get the result.again webview content touched..

Comment: try  android:focusable="false"